# while(list = each) not working properly for $_GET inside of an ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, get, while-loop, each

Alright, so here is the code that I am calling from within the js file:
(Yes, I know it's PHP code; My site handles js files as php with .htaccess, and then sends the appropriate content-type header to the browser to handle it at the end. I.E content-type: application/javascript)

```
<?php
if (count($_GET)>0) {
    print_r($_GET);
    while(list($key, $value) = each($_GET)) {
        echo $key." - ".$value."\n";
        }
    } else {
    echo "alert('no get?');";
    }
?>
```

My problem is this:

It outputs the array from print_r correctly, I.E:

```
 Array
    (
    [name%3A1] => 
    [call_id] => 0
    [_] => 1339598074533
    )
```

But, it refuses to use the `while(list($key, $index) = each($_GET))`

Any ideas why I can't go through the `$_GET` var? Maybe I typed something wrong?
The url that the ajax request sends to is: http://preview.tinyurl.com/bnpe8fe

Also, it seems every time I use post as the type, instead of get, it doesn't send the post data correctly (it doesn't send it at all);
Is there any way to use `POST` data with an ajax request to a js file instead of `GET`?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `foreach`? e.g.

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```

[PHP foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)